# Change application localization in runtime

Tags: localization, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In Windows Phone 7 it's possible to easily change the application locale just by setting:

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

And then the application loads resources from the file AppResources.de-DE.resx no matter what's the default app culture or current culture on the target phone.

The question is: **Is something like this possible in WinRT - Windows 8 apps?** And if yes, how? The basic problem here is that there is no Thread object.

Comment: First Google result: [WIndows 8 Application resources and localization](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
```